# Acceleometer Noise and FFT

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, noise

Background: I'm fairly new to signal processing and sensors, etc. I'm working on my thesis, which involves the use of an MEMS acceleration sensor as a vibration measuring device (for rotating machinery). I managed to extract the data from the sensor and save it to my computer. Now, I'm doing post-processing on the data with python. Basically I'm getting accelerations in X, Y ,Z axis and the time (milli seconds).

Problem: the signal is noisy and I'm getting strange results when I perform FFT to it.

I already did detrend (to remove the huge spike at 0 Hz) and used a window function (on the detrended data) to get a cleaner Fourier Transformation but still I'm not sure if what I'm getting is normal.

[image: This is data I get from the sensor. Blue: original data, Orange: after detrend, Green: after applying the window function. I applied the window function to all 3 but only showed it on the X]
*Above is data I get from the sensor. Blue: original data, Orange: after detrend, Green: after applying the window function. I applied the window function to all 3 but only showed it on the X*

[image: Here is the FFT of the data, with only unto 4 Hz on the frequency axis. Blue: FFT on detrended signal, Orange: FFT on the windowed signal]
*Above is the FFT of the data, with only unto 4 Hz on the frequency axis. Blue: FFT on detrended signal, Orange: FFT on the windowed signal*

[image: FFT of same data but full frequency axis]
*FFT of same data but full frequency axis*

The measurements were taken while the sensor was not moving with a sampling rate of 1 kHz. Also, using the sensor's low pass filter of 184Hz.

Am I on the right path? Are these results to be expected? Or is there something wrong with my work?

I hope you guys can help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: all of those questions should be directed to your supervisor. If he can not answer it, you should consider replacing him.

Comment: @GideonGenadiKogan He gave me some hints as of what to do but it looks like he wants to see better results.